# Complex Arcsin possible definition

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Is this a valid definition for arcsin?
$$\sin\theta=z$$
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
$$-\biggl(e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta\biggr)$$
$$e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}=2i\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}=\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{ie^{-i\theta}-ie^{i\theta}}{2}=\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{ie^{-i\theta}-ie^{i\theta}}{2}=z$$
$$\frac{i}{e^{i\theta}}-ie^{i\theta}=2z$$
$$\frac{-1}{ie^{i\theta}}-ie^{i\theta}=2z$$
$$\frac{-1-ie^{2i\theta}}{ie^{i\theta}}=2z$$
$$-1-ie^{2i\theta}=2zie^{i\theta}$$
$$ie^{2i\theta}+2zie^{i\theta}+1=0$$
$$(ie^{i\theta}+z)^2-z^2+1=0$$
$$(ie^{i\theta}+z)^2=z^2-1$$
$$ie^{i\theta}+z=\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$$
$$ie^{i\theta}=-z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$$
$$e^{i\theta}=(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1})i$$
$$e^{i\theta}=(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1})e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$$
$$i\theta=\ln(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1})+\frac{i\pi}{2}$$
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1})i$$
Therefore
as $\arcsin(z)=\theta$ 
$$\arcsin(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln\Bigl(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1}\Bigr)i = \theta +2A\pi$$
you can do ln of any complex number so this should be defined for all complex numbers right? Unless its incorrect

Comment: If $\sin \theta =z$ then $\sin (\theta +2k\pi)=z$. So before computing $\arcsin $ you should ask yourself where $\sin \theta $ is one-to-one.

Comment: so it should be $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln\Bigl(2z\mp\sqrt{4z^2+1}\Bigr)i = \theta +2A\pi$$ or $$\arcsin(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln\Bigl(2z\mp\sqrt{4z^2+1}\Bigr)i +2A\pi$$

Comment: $i e^{2i\theta}+2 z i e^{i\theta}-1 = 0$ is right, but you made a mistake in completing the square in the next equation.

Comment: Ah thank you. I have edited it to be correct

Comment: Also had missed a divide by i so now that is corrected also

Comment: You will have to specify what branches you are using for the square root and the logarithm.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/trigonometry-is-a-complex-subject.html